# Inherit (?) IdentityUser from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have multiple projects in my solution, all .NET Core 3.1. One of them is my core project (“**A Project**”) where I just have basic model classes with no methods or database access. For demonstration purposes, below are simplified versions of my `Address.cs` and `User.cs` files:

```
public class Address 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string AddressText {get;set;}
     public virtual User User {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public int UserName {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Address> {get;set;}
}
```

In another project (“**B Project**”), I will be building the actual functionality. This project already has ASP.NET Core Identity setup with an `ApplicationUser` class, which derives from `IdentityUser` and adds some custom properties.

This is where I run into my problem. The `Address.User` property has to be set to an instance of `ApplicationUser`, but `ApplicationUser` lives in the **B Project**.

Obviously, I don't have ASP.NET Core Identity set up as a dependency within my **A Project**, so I can't move the `ApplicationUser` class into that project. Further, I cannot assign the `ApplicationUser` to the `Address.User` property since `ApplicationUser` doesn’t derive from `User`.

Having done some research, I found a couple of different suggestions. One proposal is to use a separate project for the ASP.NET Core Identity components and then reference it alongside my **A Project** from within my **B Project**. Another soul suggested creating my own `UserStore`.

I don't want my **A Project** to be dependent upon anything. But I don’t have enough experience to decide what option is preferable for my scenario.

Comment: In the `User` class that you have, I would specify `IdentityUser`, like 
`public class User : IdentityUser`, then I know that the `startup.cs` class will need some editing, maybe this article will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: I have created my own `User` class before but I created a project with 'Individual User Accounts', this was easier because it created the `Migrations` for me after I specified the classes, but hopefully that article helps

Comment: Hello janzen. My User class, in fact the whole Core project itself, should now nothing about IdentityUser. That is the whole purpose. I am trying to build a loosly coupled n-tier application.

Comment: My bad I misread the question.

Comment: What is the function of the user table and ApplicationUser table in your design?
We need to know what your purpose to create them, then we can confirm their relationship.

Comment: ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser in order to extend it to include other properties such as DOB, Gender etc. This is a simplified shopping app. I am using IdentityCore to store user info and handle authentication and authorization issues. My core project have all other classes such as Orders, Addresses,OrderHistory etc. which all require some kind of an association with the User. I can go ahead and introduce a FK int field in the core project classes itself but I am trying to find out the way this is handled correctly.

Comment: @SubliminalHash why dont use standard `IdentityUser` and pass those properties to User class? Aren't they part of your domain like `Address`?  Then you could use `IdentityUser` only for authorization and it would not be necessary for `User` to know anything about `IdentityUser` ? Ofc, you could logically join 'em by `UserName` (if it is an email from IdentityUser) if you need to (like to get current user from database via abstraction like Repository or domain Service). Or you could make One-to-One relationship in B project

Comment: Example on how to get current user : `var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; var user = _userService.GetByUserName(userName)` . Where `_userService` is `IUserService` that is working with your `User` class

Comment: @SubliminalHash: This is a good question. As you may have noticed, I made a number of edits to your post. I hope this is alright. Most were just wording changes, but I also provided a more detailed explanation of why `ApplicationUser` can’t be moved to your core project, or referenced from your `User` property, since that appears to be at the heart of your question. I also corrected a tag to make sure this gets in front of the right community. (There are separate tags for ASP.NET Identity and ASP.NET Core Identity.)

Comment: One additional question: How are you populating your models? Are you manually constructing them via e.g., a custom repository? Or are these part of an O/RM, such as Entity Framework (EF) Core? If the former, the approach I recommend in my answer is likely your best bet. If the latter, though, you’ll find that instructing an O/RM to identify a concrete implementation of an interface from a separate assembly introduces a lot of complexity. In that case, @RomanKalinchuk‘s suggestion is a much simpler approach. (Roman, I’d definitely recommend submitting your suggestion as an answer, if you can.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have definitely painted myself into this particular corner before!

There are a few strategies you can take to resolve this, including the two you listed. The approach I‘d recommend, however, is to use [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/).

### Summary

Instead of having a concrete `User` *class*, you’ll instead have an `IUser` *interface* which you’ll reference from the models in **Project A**. You’ll then apply the `IUser` interface to your `ApplicationUser` class. This will allow instances of `ApplicationUser` to be assigned to your e.g. `Address.User` property, despite the fact that `Address` isn’t aware of `ApplicationUser`.

### Example

In **Project A**, you’ll update your classes to something  like the following:

```cs
public class Address 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string AddressText {get;set;}
     public virtual IUser User {get;set;}
}

public interface IUser
{
    int UserId {get;set;}
    int UserName {get;set;}
    ICollection<Address> {get;set;}
}
```

Then, in **Project B**, you’ll apply the `IUser` interface to your `ApplicationUser` class and ensure it implements the required properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser, IUser 
{
  … 
  public int UserId {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Address> {get;set;}
}
```

> *Note:* You don’t need to implement `UserName`, as that’s already been implemented on `IdentityUser`. Though, of course, you can always override the property, should the need arise (e.g., to add validation attributes).

### Limitations

When you access e.g., your `Address.User` property, you’ll only be able to access the members you defined on `IUser`. If you need to access any additional members defined on either `ApplicationUser` or `IdentityUser`, you will first need to cast your `IUser` reference to an `ApplicationUser`; e.g.,

```
var user = address.User as ApplicationUser;
var emailConfirmed = user?.EmailConfirmed?? false;
```

Of course, if you *know* you’re going to need access to these members, you can just make sure they’re defined on your interface, and not have to worry about this.

### Caveats

There are a couple of considerations worth being aware of. These may not apply to you, but I want to include them for completeness.

#### O/RM

As mentioned in my comment, if you’re using an O/RM to populate your models—such as Entity Framework (EF) Core—you may run into problems identifying a concrete implementation of your interface in a separate assembly. This can be done, but it definitely adds complexity which you may not want to contend with! If you’re manually constructing your object graph, though, this won’t be an issue.

#### Identity vs User Models

The `IdentityUser` is meant to represent the *currently authenticated user*, not a *general user reference*. For instance, in an e-commerce app, it doesn’t make sense to construct an `IdentityUser` for references to the seller of each product. There is obviously overlap here, and using one data source to feed both is fine. But there are also properties—such as `PasswordHash` or `SecurityStamp`—which don’t make sense to populate on a general user model. You may eventually find these needs in conflict with one another.

---

In either of the above cases, you may find it easier to differentiate between your `ApplicationUser` and your `User` classes. That’s not what you asked for, but it’s worth considering. In that case, @RomanKalinchuk‘s approach makes more sense. Though, even then, you can still unify them by applying the same `IUser` interface to each, thus ensuring they share a core set of properties.

Comment: At the risk of making my answer overly complicated, I’ve added a couple of caveats to call out scenarios which could be problematic. These may not apply to you, but I wanted to include them to be safe.

Comment: Obviously, if you did actually pass through this path before, you also are aware of the direction I am going towards with webapi and JWTs for seperate domains and projects. I accepted this answer since it actually solves my problem by eliminating other possibilities I was considering. Upvoted it since I am sure many will save time coming accross to this, and applauded just because it is a new feature here :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

It is only an opinion on how to solve this particular case

You have some domain classes like User, Address etc
And all your application domain properties are there
Like Age, Gender, FirstName, LastName, Email, ID, City, Street , those are populated by your application users, could be viewed on application personal area, used e.g. for delivery, notifications etc

And you have authorization part. There is `IdentityUser` class  (AspNetUsers table) with data about user credentials (UserName, hashed password, etc). The only usage for this data is to check which actions are available at the moment

Some actions or controllers could be marked by `Authorize` attribute and those need user to be authentificated in your system.

So domain `User` and authorization `IdentityUser` classes could exist entirely separate from each other and this will satisfy your needs

But how should you get current domain user?

You could do it like this

```
public interface IUserService
{
    User GetUserByEmail(string email);
}

[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public User GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return _userService.GetUserByEmail(userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Your answer is a complementary addition to Jeremy's answer by giving an example on the implementation hence it does help me too. So thank you very much!