# Where to store additional user information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have generated asp.net MVC project from a template in Visual Studio with login and register functionality, so I have automatically generated AccountViewModel class for storing user email address and password. Now I need to add new information about a user (for example list of bought items) and I don't know whether these information should be stored in AccountViewModel.cs or I should create a separate User class. If so, then the User class should have its own Id or the same Id from AccoutViewModel class? In other words, should these clasess be connected with each other? Because later on, I would like to get the currently logged in user and its data.

These are user classes generated form the template:

[image: generated tables]

[image: AspNetUser table]

Comment: You need to define a ```Item``` model and add a list of ```Item``` into the user

Comment: It seems that a single user has zero or more bought items. Then you need a datatable to store the bought items and keep it in relation with the AspNetUsers class using its ID as ForeignKey in your new table. If the relationship is one-to-one then you could also search how to extend the current AspNetUsers table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authentification and business models should exist separately from each other. You can check logged-in user and connect both models (auth and business) via UserName property (Email) or via  One-to-One relationship between AspNetUsers (`IdentityUser`/`ApplicationUser` class) and `User` entity class (still, it is not necessary if you could guarantee unique Emails)

You could reffer to my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62498810/8648545