# What is the best way to implement different User Roles/Permissions depending on "Project"?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

Our current API leverages ASP.Net Identity and Policy Based permissions for Authorization. It uses User Roles as claims for this. These claims are intercepted by a ClaimsTransformer class and the user permissions are read from a database containing the user mappings (cached). This all works fine.

The problem I'm having is with the API's scope expanding to include different "Projects", such that for instance, a User can be a `Creator` in one project but a `Consumer` in another. Is there a way to reconcile these requirements with .NET Core's Role/Policy based Authorization? Or is the best approach here to query the Database for these permissions upon each request?

Comment: Hi , Here is similar question , you can check if it can help you . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328729/inherit-identityuser-from-another-project)

Comment: Thank you but that link has nothing to do with what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is hard and a good starting point is to watch this video:

- [Implementing authorization in web applications and APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJeZ3YNnqz8&ab_channel=NDCConferences).

Then using the **policies** and **requirements** is how I would approach this and this resource is a good reference:

- [Custom authorisation policies and requirements in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/custom-authorisation-policies-and-requirements-in-asp-net-core/)

The picture below shows how the concept of requirements work in ASP.Net Core where you can define a requirement and then have one or many handlers independently "vote" if the user is approved or not.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've had a look at your links but having trouble understanding how this would help in my situation. Could you help translate this handler-based approach into my problem statement?

Comment: In the handlers you can then have them check your authorization database for example.  I think the main point is to first of all keep authentication (Who the user is) separate from what is he allowed to do (Authorization). The the approach is to go away from focusing on roles and instead focusing on claims, like, a doctor, can both be a doctor and patient.